# How to call method at fixed time android?

Tags: android

How do i call specific method at particular time in my android app

suppose I have to call startService() method at fix time which is provided by user. Only on that time startService() method automatic going to execute.

Do not know how to start. graceful to anyone suggest me direction of solution. i mean which functionality I have to implement.

Comment: Look up `AlarmManager`.

Comment: AlarmManager has setReping Methed

Comment: @Egon N & Naveen Tamrakar, Thanks for the interest. I also got many suggestion on AlarmManager, which would be easy way to implement.

Comment: Use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` in conjunction with `AlarmManager` to give control to your service on a desired frequency. You can see this in action in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast).

Comment: @CommonWare , Got it. Sample helps me lot. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AlarmManager` to do it.

Method Example: Waking CPU every 10 minutes until the phone turns off.

Add to Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
```

Code:

```
    package YourPackage;
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {    
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {   
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
             wl.acquire();

             // Put here YOUR code.
             Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

             wl.release();
         }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context)
     {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
 }
```

Set Alarm from Service:

```
package YourPackage;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();       
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
         alarm.SetAlarm(YourService.this);
     return START_STICKY;
}



    public void onStart(Context context,Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(context);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you want set alarm repeating at phone boot time:

Add permission to Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

<receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And create new class:

```
package YourPackage;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            alarm.SetAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need or want `:remote` on the `<receiver>` element. Your `WakeLock` handling in `onReceive()` is pointless. And you are not actually invoking the service anywhere, which is specifically what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

For example, if you are looking to start a service every couple of minutes

```
long repeatTimeInMillis = getUserRepeatTimeInMillis();

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        context,
        0,
        new Intent(context, ServiceToStart.class),
        0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + repeatTimeInMillis,
        repeatTimeInMillis, 
        pendingIntent)
```

If you need to execute some other code every couple of minutes then instead of a service you could use a broadcast receiver and use the getBroadcast static method from PendingIntent.

For more detailed information check out Google's documentation about the AlarmManager.

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Make sure you read what the differences are between the different alarm types (ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC, RTC_WAKUP) as they change the behavior of the alarm.